# how to add uservoice as submodule in eclipse

Tags: android-library, android-build

I've cloned the repository and defined it as a submodule.
I've followed the instructions for Eclipse - https://github.com/uservoice/uservoice-android-sdk
However this project is built for Android studio with the Gradle dependency.When working in Eclipse it is missing 2 Jars -

```
signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar
signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar
```

Which the project requires in order to run.
 But if I add them I won't be able to commit. Does anyone know a solution for this?